# How to read weekdays from a csv file and make a compresion in python?

Tags: python, csv

My code is following like this:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
get_time=lambda x:datetime.strptime(x, '%A').strftime('%A')

with open('days.csv') as f:
   d1=[get_time(row[0]) for row in csv.reader(f)]

for n in d1
  if n== Saturday or Sunday (how to show it in python??)
    print('yes')
 else:
   print('no')
```

Can someone help me to show `if n == Saturday or Synday` in python!

Comment: Please add csv content.

Comment: @Destrif, the csv file just include days name like : Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday...

Comment: `if n=='Saturday' or n=='Sunday':
    print('yes')`

Comment: @varunsinghal yes it's fine now!

Comment: why do you complicating your life? why? why? :) why you need `get_time`?
you have a string in row[0] so, remove get_time - it is redundant here. second: this `if` can be written using "in" operator: `if n in ['Saturday', 'Sunday']:`